# AngularJS : Select list bound by id, how to get the selected text?

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="definition in definitions">
...
<select ng-options='source.Id as (source.Author + " " + source.Desc) for source in sources' ng-model="definition.SourceId"></select>

//TODO:
<p>{{ SELECTED TEXT HERE }}</p>
<p>{{ selectedSource.Author + " " + selectedSource.Desc + " " + selectedSource.Year}}</p>

</div>
```

What is the easiest way to show the selected text from a select list where the ng-model is the id? Or better yet, how can I get the selected source object?

The solutions I find is to use the object as the ng-model on the select, but I can't do that in this case, I need to save the SourceId in my definition model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a way to make it work. My model is now definition._source and I update my definition.SourceId on change.

```
<div ng-repeat="definition in definitions" ng-controller="definitionController">
...
<select ng-change="definition.SourceId = definition._source.Id" 
        ng-model="definition._source" 
        ng-options='source as (source.Author + " " + source.Desc) for source in sources'></select>
</div>
```

To have my initial value, I added a controller to my ng-repeat where I filter the sources to get the selected source.

```
function definitionController($scope) {
    var source = $filter("filter")($scope.sources, { Id: $scope.definition.SourceId }, true);
    if (source.length == 1) {
        $scope.definition._source = source[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the whole object, and then show the property you want.

In the following code, I change `source.Id as...` to `source as...`:

```
<select ng-options='source as (source.Author + " " + source.Desc) for source in sources' 
        ng-model="definition">
</select>
```

You can now display the property you want:

```
<p>{{definition.Author}} {{definition.Desc}} {{definition.Year}}</p>
```

---

*Note I also changed `definition.SourceId` to `definition`.*

Comment: But now, I don't have the initial selected item from _definition.SourceId_.

Comment: @user2639580 You can still access it with `definition.SourceId`. `SourceId` is a property of your `definition` object.

Comment: I mean, when the page load, my list doesn't have a selected item, because there is no link in _definition_ between _SourceId_ and _source_.